# OA and OB inserted by emacs

Tags: keystrokes

What are the `OA` and `OB` inserted by emacs?

It happens, I think, when I press  <kbd>ESC</kbd>  several times. I use `emacs` in the `-nw` mode.

I would rather do without these insertions.

Comment: Are you using Emacs in a terminal? Try looking at lossage (`F1 l`) after you encounter this problem.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 I updated the question.

Comment: I can reproduce a similar effect with `emacs -Q -nw` in `(GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.20) of 2017-09-11)` on `mintty` . Pressing `ESC ESC <down>` inserts `OB` and `ESC ESC <up>` inserts `OA`. `describe-key` `ESC ESC <up>` says `ESC ESC ESC runs the command keyboard-escape-quit`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In text terminals, many keys (like <kbd>up</kbd>) work by sending a sequence of bytes, such as `ESC O A`.  Emacs normally recognizes these sequences and turns them into a more meaningful `up` event, using `input-decode-map`.  But there's no way for Emacs to know for sure whether you hit <kbd>up</kbd> or you hit <kbd>ESC O A</kbd>.  So if you type <kbd>ESC ESC up</kbd>, Emacs will see `ESC ESC ESC O A` and will think that's what you typed (because `ESC ESC ESC` is a valid key sequence, so it will first consume this and then will see `O A` separately which it won't recognize as a part of the escape sequence of <kbd>up</kbd>).

Comment: Similarly, <kbd> ESC ESC right </kbd> produces `OC` and <kbd> ESC ESC left </kbd> produces `OD`.